# How to unwrap rxjava objects in apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

In camel route I want to unwrap Single and pass String down to next method .
For project reactor there is a **UnwrapStreamProcessor** that can be used, like this:

```
from(reactive-streams:myStream)
.bean(myService, "getName")
.process(new UnwrapStreamProcessor())
.bean(myService, "getUserByName")
```

MyService.java

```
public Single<String> getName() {
 //will be rest call
}

public Single<User> getUserByName(String name) {
 //will be rest call
}
```

unfortunately UnwrapStreamProcessor won't work with RxJava(as it expects Publisher(Mono or Flux)), maybe there is an analogue of this processor for RxJava or other way to unwrap value?

PS: I could try wrapping it with adapter RxJava3Adapter.singleToMono, but it looks like an overkill for simple operation.